# How do you do Polymerase Chain Reaction (PCR) if you don't have a thermal cycler?

Tags: molecular-biology, pcr

PCR has three steps: Denaturation, Annealing, and Primer extension. Let's say you do not have a thermal cycler in the lab, how would you mimic similar conditions and perform PCR?

Comment: three water baths and patience

Comment: Worth noting that three reasonably accurate water baths might cost more (and definitely take up more space) than a small, cheap thermal cycler

Answer (score 1):

Use of 3 water baths was the original method. Perhaps isothermal amplification an option? Many reagents change colour upon amplification to visually identify successful pcr, which could make screening faster.